# Buttons go on the same address

Tags: html

I have the following html code

```
gogu@yahoo.com wants to be your partner. Do you agree? 
<br><input type="button" id="1" name="btn1" class="button" value="Yes"  onclick="window.location='confirm/gogu@yahoo.com';" />     
<input type="button" id="2" name="btn2" class="button" value="No"  onclick="window.location='decline/gogu@yahoo.com';" />
```

The problem is when i click on the No button it gets me on the same address confirm/gogu@yahoo.com.

How can i redirect properly?

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: Google Chrome and Internet Explorer

Comment: Well I'm stumped. I just created a standalone .html file with your code in it, and did a JSFiddle and both seem to navigate correctly... :-(

Comment: http://secret-of-passion.co.uk/test.html here is a test page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using window.location.href=